# Check order row depending on result query in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table checks2:

```
AllTaskNo int,
CheckQuosimaNo int,
Masroof numeric(18,3),
Maqbood numeric(18,3),
Date1 smalldatetime
```

I have a query to get balance:

```
SELECT 
    AllTaskNo
    ,CheckQuosimaNo
    ,Masroof
    ,Maqbood
    ,Date
    ,(SELECT 0 + SUM(Maqbood - Masroof) AS Expr1
        FROM Checks2 AS t2
          WHERE (BankNo = 6) 
            AND (CheckQuosimaNo <= Checks2.CheckQuosimaNo) 
            AND (Date1 BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2014', 103) 
            AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '31/10/2015', 103)) AND AllTaskNo 
            IN (SELECT No
                  FROM AllTasks
                    WHERE (BankNo = 6) 
                      AND (Date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2014', 103) 
                      AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '31/10/2015', 103))))) AS NetAmount
FROM         
    Checks2
WHERE     
    (BankNo = 6) 
    AND 
    (Date1 BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2014', 103) 
    AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '31/10/2015', 103))
ORDER BY 
    BankNo
    ,Date1
    ,CheckQuosimaNo
```

the result is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KVay.jpg)

I need to make a formula (like excel for example NetAmount = NetAmount before + Maqbood - Masroof) 
I expect that the selected row in NetAmount = 656360 but then query produce NetAmount=5567675.976

How can I fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been solve my problem by my own solution ... I think there is a shorter solution .. but any way I get what I want... My solution is:
1- Make a table (Checks3) with a new field named (rank) which is the correct order of the command result.
2- Create a new command mostly like the first one containing the (bank balance formula).
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Checks3]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)  drop table [dbo].[Checks3]

SELECT     Checks2.BankNo, Checks2.AllTaskNo, Checks2.CheckQuosimaNo, Checks2.Masroof, Checks2.Maqbood, Checks2.Date1, rank() OVER (ORDER BY checks2.date1, checks2.CheckQuosimaNo) as rank 
INTO Checks3 
FROM         Checks2 INNER JOIN
AllTasks ON Checks2.AllTaskNo = AllTasks.No where Checks2.BankNo =6 and (Checks2.[Date1] BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/10/2015', 103) AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'31/10/2015', 103)) ORDER BY CHECKS2.BankNo, CHECKS2.CheckQuosimaNo

SELECT Checks3.AllTaskNo, Checks3.CheckQuosimaNo, Checks3.Masroof, Checks3.Maqbood, Checks3.Date1, 
 ( SELECT 0+SUM(t2.Maqbood - t2.Masroof) FROM Checks3 t2
   WHERE t2.BankNo =6 and t2.rank <= Checks3.rank
         and (t2.[Date1] BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/10/2014', 103) AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'31/10/2015', 103))
  ) as NetAmount 
  FROM  Checks3 
  where Checks3.BankNo =6 and (Checks3.[Date1] BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/10/2014', 103) AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'31/10/2015', 103)) ORDER BY CHECKS3.RANK

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to do this like Over and Correlated Sub Queries

Over:

```
SELECT 
AllTaskNo ,Maqbood , Masroof,
SUM(-1*Maqbood +Masroof) OVER (ORDER BY AllTaskNo ) AS NetAmount 
FROM Checks2 T1
```

Correlated Sub Queries (Need Sql server 2014+)

```
SELECT 
AllTaskNo ,Maqbood , Masroof,
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(-1*Maqbood +Masroof) 
    FROM Checks2 T2 
        WHERE T2.AllTaskNo <=T1.AllTaskNo 
) AS NetAmount FROM Checks2 T1
```

Feel free to comment if you need any further assistance on this item

Comment: Thanks Pouria, but there is no news the same way i used in my question, you suggested that AllTaskNo as the ordered field. But it is not. The important field is CheckQuosimaNo where it cannot order in the sql statement.